# Check list against another list using two criteria for match

Tags: trigger

Ok, I am rusty and cannot think through how to do this. I am creating records in a custom object called Contest_Tracking__c. I want to make sure that an existing record doesn't already exist but need to check on two criteria.

Here is the slimmed down code. I put *** where I am stuck.

```
trigger BCI_U_Transcript_Trigger on BCI_U_Transcript__c (after insert) {
    
    //Create lists
    List<Contest_Tracking__c>   conTrack            = new list<Contest_Tracking__c>();
    List<Contest_Tracking__c>   conTrackExisting    = new list<Contest_Tracking__c>();
    List<String>                userList            = new list<String>();
    
    //Analyze each record submitted to trigger
    for(BCI_U_Transcript__c ts : Trigger.New) {
        
        String trophyName;
        String contestName;
        
        //Excel Cert
        IF(ts.loid__c == '570d5212-5bf7-4dc7-923c-7671901bfb00' || ts.loid__c == 'edd930c7-0b43-4ec0-89e3-8adef093d3ab')
        {
            trophyName = 'Excel Cert';
            contestName = 'Excel Certification';
        }
        
/* Other if conditions removed for posting*/
        
        //Build Contest Tracking Record
        IF (trophyName != Null)
        {
            conTrack.add(new Contest_Tracking__c(
                Contest_Name__c = contestName,
                RecordTypeId    = Schema.SObjectType.Contest_Tracking__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Certification').getRecordTypeId(),
                Trophy__c       = trophyName,
                Related_To__c   = ts.CRMUserID__c,
                Trophy_Type__c  = 'Certification',
                User__c         = ts.CRMHubID__c
            ));
        }
        
    }
    
    //Check list against current records to ensure we don't award more than once. 
    if(!conTrack.isempty())
    {
        //Get list of users
        For(Contest_Tracking__c ct:ConTrack)
        {
                userList.add(ct.User__c);
        }
        //Get existing trophies for these users
        conTrackExisting = [Select Id,Name,Trophy__c,User__c FROM Contest_Tracking__c WHERE User__c IN :userList];
        
        //Check if new trophy already exists in this list
        For(Contest_Tracking__c ct:ConTrack)
        {
                ***Stuck here***
                    Need to compare the two lists together.
                    Need to check two criteria: User__c and Trophy__c
                        ****
        }
    }
    
    //Insert records
    if(!conTrack.isempty())
    {
            insert conTrack;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: I came up with this but it seems a bit ugly/clunky.

Comment: //Create key for comparison
        For(Contest_Tracking__c ct:conTrackExisting)
        {
            conTrackKeys.add(ct.User__c + ct.Trophy__c);
        }
        
        //Only pass new records
        For(Contest_Tracking__c ct:conTrack)
        {
            if(!conTrackKeys.contains(ct.User__c + ct.Trophy__c))
            {
                conTrackInsert.add(ct);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat more elegant solution that doesn't rely on a concatenated string composite key (I also renamed your variables)

```
Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Contest_Tracking__c ct: conTracks) {
  userIds.add(ct.User__c);   // decide if you want to ignore nulls
}
Set<Contest_Tracking__c> existingKeys = new Set<Contest_Tracking__c>();
for (Contest_Tracking__c existingCT : [SELECT Trophy__c, User__c 
                                        FROM Contest_Tracking__c WHERE User__c IN :userIds]) {
  existingKeys.add(new Contest_Tracking__c(Trophy__c = existingCt.Trophy__c,
                                           User__c = existingCt.User__c));
}

for (Contest_Tracking__c ct: conTracks) {
   if (existingKeys.contains(new Contest_Tracking__c(Trophy__c = ct.Trophy__c,
                                                     User__c = ct.User__c)) {
     insertableConTracks.add(ct);
   }
}
insert insertableConTracks;
```

*Notes*:

1. Use an Sobject to represent the composite key. Provided all elements of the composite key exist as fields on the sobject, this is extensible to 2,3,4,... elements
2. Get rid of the last test for `isEmpty` -- the insert of an empty list does not burn any DML. Less-is-more.

Comment: Isn't this considered bad method as you are doing SOQL inside of a FOR/Each loop? Thinking about governor limits.  My solution keeps the operation at just 1 SOQL query.

Comment: this was not the whole trigger, it goes after your line `//Check list against current records to ensure we don't award more than once. 
    if(!conTrack.isempty())
    {`  There's no soql inside a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well this works but not sure if it is the most efficient way of doing it. Just sharing.

```
  //Check list against current records to ensure we don't award more than once. 
    if(!conTrack.isempty())
    {
        //Get list of users
        For(Contest_Tracking__c ct:ConTrack)
        {
                userList.add(ct.User__c);
        }
        //Get existing trophies for these users
        conTrackExisting = [Select Id,Name,Trophy__c,User__c 
                            FROM Contest_Tracking__c 
                            WHERE User__c IN :userList];
        
        //Create key for comparison
        For(Contest_Tracking__c ct:conTrackExisting)
        {
            conTrackKeys.add(ct.User__c + ct.Trophy__c);
        }
        
        //Only pass new records
        For(Contest_Tracking__c ct:conTrack)
        {
            if(!conTrackKeys.contains(ct.User__c + ct.Trophy__c))
            {
                conTrackInsert.add(ct);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //Insert records
    if(!conTrackInsert.isempty())
    {
            insert conTrackInsert;
    }
```